# BigQuery how to an hours worth of data with a 30 minute delay?

Tags: google-bigquery

hello guys using this query to get all jobs of the project but lets say I run this query at noon , 12:00, it should get data from 10:30 to 11:30  but I havent yet been able to figure out where clause in order to achieve  this  any ideas how this would be implemented?

```
           SELECT
           creation_time,
           start_time,
           end_time,
           total_bytes_processed,
           query
           FROM `project-id.region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT`
           where end_time > TIMESTAMP_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL -1 hour )  AND job_type = "QUERY"
           Group BY creation_time, start_time,end_time ,job_id, total_bytes_processed, query
           ORDER BY total_bytes_processed DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() is 12 and you are looking for the jobs that were created between 10:30 and 11, then you should use the BETWEEN operator.

```
SELECT
  creation_time,
  start_time,
  end_time,
  total_bytes_processed,
  query
FROM
  `YOURPROJECT.region-eu.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT`
WHERE
  end_time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 90 MINUTE) 
           AND     TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) 
  AND job_type = "QUERY"
GROUP BY
  creation_time,
  start_time,
  end_time,
  job_id,
  total_bytes_processed,
  query
ORDER BY
  total_bytes_processed DESC
```

Comment: 10:30 and 11:30 so it will 120 minutes and 30 minutes right?

Comment: Yes! that's it. You can test that by only running "SELECT TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 120 MINUTE) as time "